# Hand Edit A Jar to Change Package Names

Tags: java, maven

I have a jar file from an external source. All of the classes in the jar are in the com.xyz package.

I would like to move all of classes to the com.xyzold package.

Is this is simple as unzipping the jar, renaming the xzy folder to xyzold, and rezipping it, or do I need to modify each class file as well?

---

Here's my solution, using [Jar Jar Links](https://github.com/shevek/jarjar)

```
java -jar jarjar-1.4.jar process rules.txt google-collections-1.0.jar google-collections-old-1.0.jar
```

And here's the contents of my rules.txt file:

```
rule com.google.** com.googleold.@1
```

Comment: why do you need to move classes to different package?

Comment: They have a new project, which uses the same package and class names. It was supposed to be fully backward compatible but isn't. We have an very large codebase that depends on the old version.

Comment: That command line invocation doesn't work with the version of jarjar I found at https://github.com/hannesa2/jarjar/releases/tag/1.0.3. Parameters have to be passed with "--" e.g. `java -jar "jarjar-command-1.0.3.jar" --mode process --rules "rules.txt" in.jar --output out.jar`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [Jar Jar Links](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/) to achieve that. Also you don't need the source code of the classes you'd like to modify, as the program does it on the bytecode level (ie. it modifies the .class files directly.)

Comment: Is there something newer ?

Comment: @expert I used it and worked. Still sounds useful

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv how to used it I`ve been looking tutorial on youtube using the Jar Jar Links  but couldn`t find one

Comment: The only thing I remember is that I read the `--help` or `-h`. Use the jar's helper

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on classnames involving the `$` character? See https://github.com/shevek/jarjar/issues/29

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) to do this in a Maven build.

Comment: This worked for me. Though it did introduce extra classes from my project into the jar that I didn't need, so I had to delete them manually (by unzipping/zipping using jar)

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Jar Jar Links](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/). (I'm not taking any responisibility for the name :).)

Its primary use case is to embed external jars in your own jar, and to do that, it can re-name existing packages. It changes the necessary byte code. You might be able to tweak it to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this with the [ProGuard obfuscator](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). It can certainly move code around in packages and operates at the byte code level. Its primary aim is obfuscation though so one of the other options should certainly be looked at first.

Answer (score -4):

No you need to modify all the classes in jar file. You need to have a source code in-order to change package.

Answer (score -4):

You would need to modify all the Java source files too. Not just the package names but the imports too, and any possible inline declarations. Not really worth it.