# Can I somehow include and use multiple versions of a given .jar library?

Tags: java, android

I appreciate that this might sound absurd, but is it possible to drop two different versions of a .jar library into an Android project (where both versions obviously have identical or overlapping package and class names), and somehow explicitly point to one of them when importing the library's classes into my own Java sources?

My development environment is Android Studio with Gradle.

My reason for considering doing this (if it is possible) is because I rely on a closed-source vendor-supplied .jar driver library for a USB device that my Android application works with. The vendor has added support for newer chip versions in their latest driver, but at the same time they have dropped support for older chip versions. This is a decision they have made for their own good reason and it is unlikely to be reversed. An idea I have is to somehow carry both old and new versions of the library in my application so that I can continue to support the older hardware.

I suppose something like this would be theoretically possible, but a complicated affair, perhaps requiring one .jar to be decompiled and package names changed?

Comment: You would need to use something like **`jarjar`** to repackage one of the JARs, short of playing some nasty classloader games.

Comment: The order of those JAR files in CLASSPATH matters. Which ever comes first, that JAR classes will be loaded (since the namespace is same).

Comment: Thanks gents, your input is much appreciated. The `jarjar` suggestion is a very interesting one.

Comment: Interesting question. I'd ask you if you have the original sources to the jar file. How does the decompiled version look like, is it readable?

Comment: I don't have the sources unfortunately. I must admit I haven't attempted to decompile it yet. I've just grabbed jarjar, though, to give that a try.

Comment: I seem to have had success! Answer now provided. Thanks for your terrific help.

Comment: another option is to include the jar as a resource, to copy it somewhere at runtime, and to load it afterwards with PathClassLoader

Answer (score 6):

To my amazement, I've very quickly had success at this using the `jarjar` utility as suggested by CommonsWare.

The key in understanding how to do this was this QA:

[Hand Edit A Jar to Change Package Names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746737/hand-edit-a-jar-to-change-package-names)

I renamed one of my `.jar`s using the directions given above and I now have them both sat side by side in my project.

I don't want to duplicate SO content, but for completeness, I did the following:

Obtained the latest version of [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/downloads/list).

Created a configuration file called `rules.txt` containing a single line:

```
rule uk.co.dog.** uk.co.cat.@1
```

That's just an example. Given a .jar with the package `uk.co.dog.*`, the `dog` will change to `cat`. Obviously change this to suit your real case.

Then use the command line:

```
java -jar jarjar.jar process rules.txt in.jar out.jar
```

Where `in.jar` is the source .jar and `out.jar` is the transformed one.